# 3, 6, 12 months ago interval pyspark

Tags: pyspark

How can I select V1 rows 3, 6, 12 months interval
Let's say there are tables like the below table

| month | V1 |
| --- | --- |
| 202307 | 10 |
| 202306 | 20 |
| 202305 | 30 |
| 202304 | 40 |
| 202303 | 50 |
| 202302 | 60 |
| 202301 | 70 |

I want to create it like the below table.
V2 is from 3 months ago, V3 comes from 6 months ago

| month | V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202307 | 10 | 30 | 60 |

Answer (score 0):

Check below.

```
df
.withColumn(
  "first_date", 
  expr("""FIRST(TO_DATE(month, 'yyyyMM')) OVER(ORDER BY month DESC)""")
)
.withColumn(
  "diff", 
   expr("""CAST(MONTHS_BETWEEN(first_date, TO_DATE(month, 'yyyyMM')) AS INT) + 1""")
)
.selectExpr("FILTER(collect_list(struct(first_date, v1, diff)),e -> e.diff == 1 OR e.diff % 3 == 0) AS list")
.selectExpr(
    "DATE_FORMAT(list.first_date[0],'yyyyMM') AS month", 
    "FILTER(list, e -> e.diff == 1).v1[0] AS V1", 
    "FILTER(list, e -> e.diff == 3).v1[0] AS V2", 
    "FILTER(list, e -> e.diff == 6).v1[0] AS V3"
)
.show(false)
```

Comment: Thank you. what if there are several String type columns additionally? for example, name, location etc.?

Comment: Please add all edge cases in your question with expected output